# How to copy all styles from one document to another when using Pages?

Tags: pages

I have multiple Pages documents with similar structure and using the same styles (Title, Body, ...). Is it possible to update the styles in one document, and then apply all the updated styles to another document? The only way I can think of is copying and pasting/updating each style individually.

Comment: save it as template.

Comment: And then, how do I apply that template to the existing document?

Comment: copy the content

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding something this does not seem like a good solution (1) you lose document history, have to save a new document (2) copy-pasting actually keeps the formatting, so you still have to go back and re-apply all the styles manually

Comment: Having a template will help you going forward. converting existing is not possible and only in manual mode.